# How Change Meta Title on Individual URL in Post Pagination Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags

I have site on wordpress, but i'am use automatic pagination every post.

On pagination, then I made an article so that all posts are visible with the url, example https://bisnis.cilacap.info/pertamina-ru-iv-cilacap-transfer-pertalite?singlepage=all. This url work and no error in cpanel.

But the Meta Title is missing, and I want to make it into existence. Can any friend help me and implement it in function.php

Comment: Does **?singlepage=all** make a difference in the content of the page?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This guide will help you to post good, answerable posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You may even find the answer for your own question when you follow the guide